# sorting groups within a query

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I am using the below query to paginate posts on my site:

```
select * from songs t1 join (
select to_days(date) day from songs 
group by day 
order by day desc 
limit $start_row, $items_per_page
) t2
on to_days(t1.date) = t2.day
```

Depending on my `$start_row` and `$items_per_page` this will return all the posts for say, the last 7 days. Regardless of if there was more than 1 post per day or a day is empty and skipped.

For example:

[image: sample results]

Above the query has correctly returned all the posts from the latest 7 days. Today. Yesterday. The day before that and so on...

However if you look at the table `id` `12##` values on the far left, and time stamp day values `73####` on the far right.  You will see they are grouped backwards.

How do I switch this query around so that it returns the same results in the same grouping but in a reverse order?

For example:

Oh My! - Run This Town(TMS remix)
Lost Mapaches-Back To Basics (La Royale Remix)

Dimitri from Paris & DJ Rocca-I Need A Reason For LIving (Radio Mix)
Chromeo - Hot Mess (23 Dubstep Remix)

and so on... I tried removing the `desc` value but that just returns the grouping from the oldest entries in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would order your data on the outside of the subquery (note the last line), please adjust last line for asc / desc or if you want to order by.

```
select * from songs t1 join (
select to_days(date) day from songs 
group by day 
order by day desc 
limit $start_row, $items_per_page
) t2
on to_days(t1.date) = t2.day
order by id desc
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add an `ORDER BY` to the outer select as well, not just the inner one being JOINed to.

```
SELECT *
FROM songs t1
JOIN (
    SELECT to_days(date) day FROM songs 
    GROUP BY day 
    ORDER BY day DESC
    LIMIT $start_row, $items_per_page
) t2 ON to_days(t1.date) = t2.day
ORDER BY day DESC
```

(That last line is the bit you need to add.)

Comment: `ORDER By day DESC` actually returns things a little strangely, cause posts share days? Maybe if I used the full datetime instead of day? http://cl.ly/3t093Z1i0E3k0Z0d1k3G +1 for clean formatting!

Comment: If you want to order by the id, change it to `ORDER BY id DESC` instead. The important point of all of this is just that you need to have an `ORDER BY` clause on the main (outer) select.